# How to render <div> only if <Trans> translation string is not empty - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, i18next

I have array of objects in React:

```
const books = [
  { 
   id:1,
   name: <Trans i18nKey="books.firstbook.name",
   description: <Trans i18nKey = "books.firstbook.description"
  },
  { 
   id:2,
   name: <Trans i18nKey="books.secondbook.name",
   description: <Trans i18nKey = "books.secondbook.description"
  },
  
]
```

in en.json file description of second book is empty:

```
"books": {
  "firstbook": {
     "name": "Pippi Longstocking",
     "description": "Pippi Longstocking is the fictional main character."
   }
 "secondbook": {
     "name": "Karlsson on the roof",
     "description": " "
   }
```

I want to render `<div>` component for each book only if it has description. I'm trying to do it like this but  for secondbook is still rendered.

```
books.map(b => 
 { 
    b.description && (
    <div> {b.description} </div>
 )}
```

Can you help me to do this? thank you

Comment: please log b.description and share the result

Answer (score 0):

The probelm is that the description of the second book is not empty, it has a whitespace. So just add the `.trim()` function

```
books.map(b => b.description && b.description.trim() ? <div> {b.description} </div> : null)
```

I added two checks just in case if `description` is null or undefined.

Comment: I got an error: "Property "trim" doesnot exist on type "Element"

Comment: Ah thats unfortunate. Your desciption element is a React component. In this case I'd recommend you to save the description text seperately in your books array. Right now it doesn't make sense to check if b.description is null or not as an element is always present and therefore it will always return true

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
books.map(b => 
 { 
    b.description && (
    <div> {b.description} </div>
 )}
```

add this

```
books.map(b => 
 { 
    b.description.props.i18nKey && (
    <div> {b.description} </div>
 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still rendered because `b.description` for second object is `" "` which is a string of length 1 , and so is not empty ,

checking string logic:
empty string => return false 
other wise return true .

There are many ways to check if a string is empty , for example :

```
books.map(b => 
 { 
    (b.description && b.description.trim())  (
    <div> {b.description} </div>
 )}
```